# Antlr Visitor with complex result

Tags: c#, vba, rubberduck, antlr

I'm currently helping out on [Rubberduck open source project](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/), specifically on the `Extract Method` functionality.

I wrote a purpose-built visitor to assist with validating the selection. Basically we have to ensure that when the user select a piece of VBA code, the selection only encompasses a set of complete statements that are also self-contained. By "self-contained", we mean:

- it is within a single procedure
- does not contain any control-of-flow statements such as `GoTo`, `On Error`, `Exit XXX` that would cause the execution to leave the selection entirely or jump into middle of the selection
- each statements are complete (e.g. not partially selected)

Note there are 2 issues already present that can be ignored:

- Hard-coded literals reporting error. Those need to be in the resource files and will be moved later. I need more thoughts on what I need to collect before I will refactor those.
- Currently, the visitor stops as soon as it encounters an invalid context. It will be revised to allow collection of all possible invalid contexts, which is why it's an `IList` rather than a single instance.

Specific questions to assess:

- To avoid storing a state in the visitor, I opted to create a class `ExtractMethodValidationResult` which importantly has 2 separate lists. `ValidContexts` gives me all contexts (of one type) that are valid for a user's selection whereas `InvalidContexts` gives me any other contexts (regardless of type) where there might be a problem. I then pass that into the generic visitor.In a typical sample, a generic visitor will take an `IEnumerable` of some certain contexts and return that. This is quite different as we take a class and return the results. As a result, the process will create many new instances of the class which is then aggregated. Are there any potential pitfalls with the approach?
- I'm not exactly thrilled with the high amount of duplicative code, notably with those that collects invalid contexts. Can this be done better?
- I'm a little fuzzy whether I need to return `base.XXX` when visiting contexts that are considered invalid. In case when we visit a invalid context that isn't a part of the selection, we execute the `base.XXX`
- I'm a bit stumped on where the responsibility of the visitor starts and stops. Right now it returns a raw set of contexts which requires additional processing outside the visit. I'm considering whether I should override the `Visit` method to something similar to this:

  ```
      public override ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> Visit(IParseTree tree)
      {
          var result = base.Visit(tree);
          return PostProcessing(result);
      }
  ```

The advantage would be that the visitor now returns a result that needs no more additional processing but it also takes on the responsibility of analyzing the returned contexts from the `base.Visit`. Have I then violated the SRP here? Thoughts?

Any other feedbacks & suggestions welcome.

Result code:

```
    private class ExtractMethodValidationResult<Result> where Result : ParserRuleContext
    {
        public IList<Result> ValidContexts { get; set; }
        public IList<Tuple<ParserRuleContext, String>> InvalidContexts { get; set; }

        public ExtractMethodValidationResult()
        {
            ValidContexts = new List<Result>();
            InvalidContexts = new List<Tuple<ParserRuleContext, String>>();
        }

        public ExtractMethodValidationResult(ParserRuleContext InvalidContext, String ErrorMessage) : this()
        {
            InvalidContexts.Add(Tuple.Create(InvalidContext, ErrorMessage));
        }
    }
```

Visitor code:

```
private class ExtractMethodValidatorVisitor : VBAParserBaseVisitor<ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext>>

    {
        private readonly QualifiedSelection _qualifiedSelection;

        public ExtractMethodValidatorVisitor(QualifiedSelection qualifiedSelection)
        {
            _qualifiedSelection = qualifiedSelection;
        }

        protected override ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> DefaultResult => new ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext>();

        public override ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> VisitBlockStmt([NotNull] VBAParser.BlockStmtContext context)
        {
            var children = base.VisitBlockStmt(context);
            if (children.InvalidContexts.Count == 0)
            {
                children.ValidContexts.Add(context);
            }

            return children;
        }

        protected override ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> AggregateResult(ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> aggregate, ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> nextResult)
        {
            if (aggregate.InvalidContexts.Count == 0)
            {
                if (nextResult != null)
                {
                    aggregate.ValidContexts = aggregate.ValidContexts.Concat(nextResult.ValidContexts).ToList();
                    aggregate.InvalidContexts = aggregate.InvalidContexts.Concat(nextResult.InvalidContexts).ToList();
                }
            }

            return aggregate;
        }

        protected override bool ShouldVisitNextChild(IRuleNode node, ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> currentResult)
        {
            // Don't visit any more children if we have any invalid contexts
            return (currentResult.InvalidContexts.Count == 0);
        }

        public override ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> VisitErrorStmt([NotNull] VBAParser.ErrorStmtContext context)
        {
            if (_qualifiedSelection.Selection.Contains(context))
            {
                return new ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext>(context, "Extract method cannot extract methods that contains an Error statement.");
            }

            return base.VisitErrorStmt(context);
        }

        public override ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> VisitEndStmt([NotNull] VBAParser.EndStmtContext context)
        {
            if (_qualifiedSelection.Selection.Contains(context))
            {
                return new ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext>(context, "Extract method cannot extract methods that contains an End statement.");
            }

            return base.VisitEndStmt(context);
        }

        public override ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> VisitExitStmt([NotNull] VBAParser.ExitStmtContext context)
        {
            if (_qualifiedSelection.Selection.Contains(context))
            {
                return new ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext>(context, "Extract method cannot extract methods that contains an Exit statement");
            }

            return base.VisitExitStmt(context);
        }

        public override ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> VisitGoSubStmt([NotNull] VBAParser.GoSubStmtContext context)
        {
            if (_qualifiedSelection.Selection.Contains(context))
            {
                return new ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext>(context, "Extract method cannot extract methods that contains a GoSub statement");
            }

            return base.VisitGoSubStmt(context);
        }

        public override ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> VisitGoToStmt([NotNull] VBAParser.GoToStmtContext context)
        {
            if (_qualifiedSelection.Selection.Contains(context))
            {
                return new ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext>(context, "Extract method cannot extract methods that contains a GoTo statement");
            }

            return base.VisitGoToStmt(context);
        }

        public override ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> VisitOnErrorStmt([NotNull] VBAParser.OnErrorStmtContext context)
        {
            if (_qualifiedSelection.Selection.Contains(context))
            {
                return new ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext>(context, "Extract method cannot extract methods that contains a On Error statement");
            }

            return base.VisitOnErrorStmt(context);
        }

        public override ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> VisitIdentifierStatementLabel([NotNull] VBAParser.IdentifierStatementLabelContext context)
        {
            if (_qualifiedSelection.Selection.Contains(context))
            {
                return new ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext>(context, "Extract method cannot extract methods that contains a Line Label statement");
            }

            return base.VisitIdentifierStatementLabel(context);
        }

        public override ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> VisitCombinedLabels([NotNull] VBAParser.CombinedLabelsContext context)
        {
            if (_qualifiedSelection.Selection.Contains(context))
            {
                return new ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext>(context, "Extract method cannot extract methods that contains a Line Label statement");
            }

            return base.VisitCombinedLabels(context);
        }

        public override ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> VisitOnGoSubStmt([NotNull] VBAParser.OnGoSubStmtContext context)
        {
            if (_qualifiedSelection.Selection.Contains(context))
            {
                return new ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext>(context, "Extract method cannot extract methods that contains a On ... GoSub statement");
            }

            return base.VisitOnGoSubStmt(context);
        }

        public override ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> VisitOnGoToStmt([NotNull] VBAParser.OnGoToStmtContext context)
        {
            if (_qualifiedSelection.Selection.Contains(context))
            {
                return new ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext>(context, "Extract method cannot extract methods that contains a On ... GoTo statement");
            }

            return base.VisitOnGoToStmt(context);
        }

        public override ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> VisitResumeStmt([NotNull] VBAParser.ResumeStmtContext context)
        {
            if (_qualifiedSelection.Selection.Contains(context))
            {
                return new ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext>(context, "Extract method cannot extract methods that contains a Resume statement");
            }

            return base.VisitResumeStmt(context);
        }

        public override ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext> VisitReturnStmt([NotNull] VBAParser.ReturnStmtContext context)
        {
            if (_qualifiedSelection.Selection.Contains(context))
            {
                return new ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext>(context, "Extract method cannot extract methods that contains a Return statement");
            }

            return base.VisitReturnStmt(context);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Excluding control flow statements makes for a simpler implementation, but eventually if a `GoTo` jump refers to a line label/number that's within the selection, the selection should be deemed valid: the visitor will eventually need to use a `DeclarationFinder` to find the declaration for the line label/number being referred to by a `GoTo` statement, and then verify that the line label/number isn't being jumped-to by statements that aren't within the selection.

Comment: That's exactly correct. This will be addressed in a future iteration. For right now it's more important to have a _functional_ Extract Method.

Comment: When I read "To avoid storing a state in the visitor", I'm tempted to ask: Could you use a listener instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Antlr visitors and listeners work, there's little we can do to avoid redundant code - you've done quite a good job at keeping the redundancies minimal.

Essentially the logic is the same in all overrides: return a `new ExtractMethodValidationResult` when `context` is contained in the user's selection, or the no-op `base` return value otherwise.

You could remove the dots and extract a generic `IsSelected<TContext>` function to turn this:

```
if (_qualifiedSelection.Selection.Contains(context)
{
    return ...
}

return ...
```

into a single `return` statement:

```
return IsSelected(context) 
    ? new ExtractMethodValidationResult<SomeParserRuleType>(context, RubberduckUI.SomeResourceKey)
    : base.VisitSomeNode(context);
```

It would be nice to be able to infer the generic type parameter from the `context`, and note the use of `RubberduckUI` resources instead of a hard-coded string literal.

That constructor's signature doesn't look right:

> ```
> public ExtractMethodValidationResult(ParserRuleContext InvalidContext, String ErrorMessage) : this()
> ```

Parameter names should be `camelCase`, and constructor chaining *usually* go the other way around (least parameters calling overloads with more parameters), but I can see why it was done this way.

Encapsulation is broken here:

> ```
>     public IList<Result> ValidContexts { get; set; }
>     public IList<Tuple<ParserRuleContext, String>> InvalidContexts { get; set; }
> ```

These properties shouldn't expose setters, these references should be immutable. You could use `private readonly` backing fields, or since Rubberduck is now written in C#7, leverage truly immutable get-only autoproperties:

```
public IList<TResult> ValidContexts { get; } = new List<TResult>();
public IList<Tuple<ParserRuleContext, string>> InvalidContexts { get; } = new List<Tuple<ParserRuleContext, string>>();
```

This would remove the need to chain the parameterized constructor overload; you'd still need to have an explicit default constructor though.

Note the use of the `string` language keyword/alias for `System.String`; Rubberduck's code base uses language aliases whenever they are available.

I'm not sure exposing `Tuple<ParserRuleContext, string>` makes the greatest API for the consuming class. The class itself being `private` tells me this would be a nested class and as such, some sort of "implementation detail" of *something bigger* (which, indeed it is) - so it might not matter much. But if the class were `public` or `internal`, I'd avoid exposing a `Tuple` like this.

Might be just a copy/paste artifact, but watch brace position:

> ```
> private class ExtractMethodValidatorVisitor : VBAParserBaseVisitor<ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext>>
>
>     {
> ```

Should be:

```
private class ExtractMethodValidatorVisitor : VBAParserBaseVisitor<ExtractMethodValidationResult<VBAParser.BlockStmtContext>>    
{
```

This check works against `IList<T>`:

> ```
> if (children.InvalidContexts.Count == 0)
> ```

Not wrong in itself, but then further encapsulating the lists and eventually exposing the contexts as `IEnumerable`s would make that code require adjustments. I'd go with LINQ here, and work against the more general-purpose `IEnumerable<T>` interface:

```
if (!children.InvalidContexts.Any())
```

The `List<T>` is an implementation detail anyway.

---

I need to learn to leverage Antlr visitors myself, to I hope another reviewer will be commenting on the general approach.

Comment: Regarding your comments about encapsulation being broken --- this is not easy (or at least not obvious to me) to fix if you look at the `AggregateResult` method where I assign the result of `Concat()` to the fields. Originally I only did the `Concat()` but was getting exceptions about the lists being empty. Thus, assigning the result of `Concat()` was necessary to ensure the list is kept populated. If you can suggest another way, I'm all eyes.